# Problema con una variable en C

Tags: c

Buenas tengo el siguiente código, en el que tengo que calcular y visualizar la suma y el producto de los números pares comprendidos entre 20 y 400 ambos inclusive. El producto me muestra siempre 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n=20;
    int sumaP=0, producto=1;

    while(n<=400)
    {
        printf(" %d ",n);
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            sumaP+=n;
            producto*=n;            
        }
        n++;
    }
    printf("\n\nLa suma total de numeros pares es: %d", sumaP);
    printf("\nEl producto total de numeros pares es: %d", producto);    

}
```

Comment: Y la suma sí te funciona bien?

Comment: Si, la suma me sale bien, es solo el resultado del producto que me sale 0.

Comment: Un detalle que acabo de ver... cuidado si estás usando dos cuentas (me parece demasiado llamativo que ambos compartáis eso de **Guiber** ). SO tiene algoritmos por detrás que pueden bloquear cuentas de granjeo y borrar puntos obtenidos ilegítimamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta en que la operación de mostrar el producto de todos los números pares hasta el 400 es una burrada de largo por eso el `int producto` solo coge hasta una cantidad de números, por eso cuando no es capaz de coger mas muestra solo un 0. Lo que he hecho ha sido cambiar el tipo de dato de producto tal que así: `unsigned long long int producto = 1;` y después visualizarlo con `%llu`

Código:

```
int main()
{
    int sumaP=0;
    unsigned long long int producto = 1;
    int n=20;

    do{
        printf(" %d ",n);
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            sumaP = sumaP + n; 
            producto*=n;    
        }        
        n++;
    }while(n<=83); 
    printf("\n\nLa suma total de numeros pares es: %d", sumaP);
    printf("\nEl producto total de numeros pares es: %llu", producto);
}
```

Pero aun así hasta el numero 400 es mucho el resultado del producto. Haciendo pruebas, producto solo me lo muestra hasta el numero del rango 83 con un resultado de: 9223372036854775808.

Si quisieras ir desde 20 hasta 84 multiplicando todos los números pares que hay entre ellos inclusive el 20 y el 84 saldría 0.

Espero haberte ayudado y aclarado las dudas.

Answer (score 2):

La justificación que te ha dado @MarioGuiber sobre el motivo del 0 no es correcta.

Todos los números pares tienen como característica común que su bit menos significativo es **siempre** 0. Al multiplicar una secuencia de pares se produce un **efecto 0**. Esto es, los bits menos significativos se van marcando todos como 0:

```
2  * 4 =   8 -> 0000 0010 * 0000 0100 = 0000 0000 1000 <- 3 bits a 0
8  * 6 =  48 -> 0000 1000 * 0000 0110 = 0000 0011 0000 <- 4 bits a 0
48 * 8 = 384 -> 0011 0000 * 0000 1000 = 0001 1000 0000 <- 7 bits a 0
...
```

Por otro lado tenemos que el tipo `int` que estás utilizando es un tipo compuesto por 32 bits (de los cuales 1 se usa para indicar el signo). Todo número que intentes almacenar que ocupe más de 32 bits verá truncados todos los bits que excedan de 32.

El efecto conjunto de estas dos características provoca que, a partir del momento en el que los primeros 32 bits de la secuencia sean 0 (situación que se produce al multiplicar por 28), el producto quedará estancado en el número 0.

De hecho, puedes observar como se van perdiendo bits con un algoritmo muy sencillo:

```
int producto = 1;
for( int i = 2; i<30; i+=2 )
{
  int resultado = producto * i;
  printf("%d * %d = %d\n",producto,i,resultado);
  if( resultado / i != producto )
    puts("\tresultado incorrecto\n");
  producto = resultado;
}
```

A partir de `i=20` los resultados empiezan a ser extraños.

Si haces como te comenta @MarioGuiber y sustituyes el tipo `int` por `unsigned long long` lo que consigues es aumentar el rango de posibles valores ya que ahora usarás 64 bits en vez de 31 (recuerda que `int` gasta un bit en el signo). Como el crecimiento del producto es exponencial poco tiempo después vuelves a tener el mismo problema de desbordamiento.